# JS Pushing object in array changes property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I tried to create separate objects and because I have to do similar task with them I pushed them into an array. Doing so seem to  change a specific property of the objects and I don't know why. I create the objects like this:

```
var lo_ro = new PB.Edge(lo, ro);
var ro_ru = new PB.Edge(ro, ru);
```

The code snippet

```
console.log(lo_ro);
console.log("+");
console.log(ro_ru);
console.log("=");
console.log([lo_ro, ro_ru]);
```

returned this (in chrome):

[image: console output]

so the owner property of each  object changes to "boardOwner"
Here is my Edge function:

```
if (!window.PB)
    window.PB = {};
... 
PB.Edge = function (start, end) {
    this.start =  start.id; //Ids of vertecies
    this.end = end.id;
    this.owner = ""; 

    this.id = "(" + start.id + ")>(" + end.id + ")";
};
PB.Edge.boardOwner = "boardOwner";
```

The "PB.Edge.boardOwner" is for other uses and I dont understand why the owner property is set to "boardOwner".

PS. Here is some more code (the comments are in german):

```
(function () {

if (!window.PB)
    window.PB = {};

PB.Item = function (typ) {
    this.typ = typ;
    //weitere Feler typspezifisch
};

PB.GoalItem = function (playerID) {
    this.typ = "goal";
    this.player = playerID;
};

PB.Vertex = function (x, y) {
    this.x =  x; //ganzzahlen  auf karrierten papier!
    this.y = y;
    this.item = null;
    if (arguments.length > 2)
        this.item = arguments[2];
    this.id = x+"|"+y;
};
PB.Vertex.getID = function (x, y) {
    return x+"|"+y;
};

PB.Edge = function (start, end) {
    this.start =  start.id; //Ids of vertecies
    this.end = end.id;
    this.owner = ""; //kein owner heisst es edge ist initial edge einer zelle
                        //ansonsten  ID vom spieler
    this.id = "(" + start.id + ")>(" + end.id + ")";
};
PB.Edge.boardOwner = "boardOwner"; //Spielfeldrand
PB.Edge.getID = function (start, end) {
    return start.id + ">" + end.id;
};

PB.Cell = function (corners) {
    this.corners =  corners; //Array von Ids von Vertecies
    this.id = corners[0].id;
    for (var i = 1; i < corners.length; i+=1)
        this.id += ":"+corners[i].id;
};
PB.Cell.getID = function (corners) {
    var  id = corners[0].id;
    for (var i = 1; i < corners.length; i+=1)
        id += ":"+corners[i].id;
    return id;
};

PB.Board = function (vertecies, edges, cells, start, player, width,  height, type) {
    this.vertecies = vertecies; //bin Suchbäume
    this.edges = edges;
    this.cells =  cells;
    this.start = start; //id zu startvertex
    this.player = player; //array von ids von playern
    this.width = width;  //max x bzw y wert eines erhaltenen Vertex
    this.height = height;
    this.type = type;
};

})();
```

and

```
(function () {

PB.RectBoard = function(player, width, height) {

    var vertecies = new BinarySearchTree();
    var edges = new BinarySearchTree();
    var cells = new BinarySearchTree();
    var start = null;
    var realh = height+2;
    var realw = player.length > 2 ? (player.length > 3 ? width+2 : width+1 ) : width;

    /**
     * @param i Koordinate der  Celle
     * @param j K...
     * @param b1 "l", "o", "r" oder "u" dort soll boardowner
     * @param b2 ...
     * @param g  "lo", "ro", "ru" oder "lu" sezt item "item"
     * @param item
     */
    function create_cell(i, j, b1, b2, g1, g2, item1, item2) {
        var lo = vertecies.get(i+"|"+j);
        if (!lo) {
            lo = new PB.Vertex(i, j);
            vertecies.push(lo);
        }
        var ro = vertecies.get((i+1)+"|"+j);
        if (!ro) {
            ro = new PB.Vertex((i+1), j);
            vertecies.push(ro);
        }
        var ru = vertecies.get((i+1)+"|"+(j+1));
        if (!ru) {
            ru = new PB.Vertex((i+1), (j+1));
            vertecies.push(ru);
        }
        var lu = vertecies.get(i+"|"+(j+1));
        if (!lu) {
            lu = new PB.Vertex(i, (j+1));
            vertecies.push(lu);
        }

        var cell = new PB.Cell([lo,ro,ru,lu]);
        cells.push(cell);

        var lo_ro = new PB.Edge(lo, ro);
        var ro_ru = new PB.Edge(ro, ru);
        var ru_lu = new PB.Edge(ru, lu);
        var lu_lo = new PB.Edge(lu, lo);

        console.log(lo_ro);
        console.log("+");
        console.log(ro_ru);
        console.log("=");
        console.log([lo_ro, ro_ru]);

        var a = [lo_ro,ro_ru,ru_lu,lu_lo];
        for (var z = 0; z < 4; z+=1) {
            if (!edges.get( a[z].id )) {
                edges.push(a[z]);
            }
        }

        if (b1 == "l" || b2 == "l") {
            lu_lo.owner = PB.Board.boardOwner;
        }
        if (b1 == "r" || b2 == "r") {
            ro_ru.owner = PB.Board.boardOwner;
        }
        if (b1 == "o" || b2 == "o") {
            lo_ro.owner = PB.Board.boardOwner;
        }
        if (b1 == "u" || b2 == "u") {
            ru_lu.owner = PB.Board.boardOwner;
        }
        if (g1 == "lo") {
            lo.item = item1;
        }
        if (g1 == "ro") {
            ro.item = item1;
        }
        if (g1 == "lu") {
            lu.item = item1;
        }
        if (g1 == "ru") {
            ru.item = item1;
        }

        if (g2 == "lo") {
            lo.item = item2;
        }
        if (g2 == "ro") {
            ro.item = item2;
        }
        if (g2 == "lu") {
            lu.item = item2;
        }
        if (g2 == "ru") {
            ru.item = item2;
        }

        //startpunkt:
        if (i == (width-1)/2 && j == (height-1)/2)
            start = lo.id;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <  width-1; i+=1) {
        for (var j = 0; j < height-1; j+=1) {
            var b1 = null;
            var b2 = null;
            if (j == 0) {
                if (!(i == (width-1)/2 || i == (width-1)/2-1))
                    b2 = "o";
            }
            if (j == height-2) {
                if (!(i == (width-1)/2 || i == (width-1)/2-1))
                    b2 = "u";
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                b1 = "l";
                if (player.length > 2)
                    if (j == (height-1)/2 || j == (height-1)/2 -1)
                        b1 = null;
            }
            if (i == width-2) {
                b1 = "r";
                if (player.length > 3)
                    if (j == (height-1)/2 || j == (height-1)/2 -1)
                        b1 = null;
            }
            create_cell(i, j, b1, b2, null, null, null, null);
        }
    }

    //Tore
    var lgoal = (width -1)/2-1;
    var ogoal = (height-1)/2-1;
    //Player1
    create_cell(lgoal,   -1, "o",  "l", "lo", "ro", new PB.GoalItem(player[0]), new PB.GoalItem(player[0]));
    create_cell(lgoal+1, -1, "o",  "r", "ro", null, new PB.GoalItem(player[0]), null);
    //Player2
    create_cell(lgoal,   height-1, "u",  "l", "lu", "ru", new PB.GoalItem(player[0]), new PB.GoalItem(player[0]));
    create_cell(lgoal+1, height-1, "u",  "r", "ru", null, new PB.GoalItem(player[0]), null);
    //Player3
    if (player.length>2){
        create_cell(-1, ogoal,   "o",  "l", "lo", "lu", new PB.GoalItem(player[0]), new PB.GoalItem(player[0]));
        create_cell(-1, ogoal+1, "u",  "l", "lu", null, new PB.GoalItem(player[0]), null);
    }
    //Player4
    if (player.length>3){
        create_cell(width-1, ogoal,   "o",  "r", "ro", "ru", new PB.GoalItem(player[0]), new PB.GoalItem(player[0]));
        create_cell(width-1, ogoal+1, "u",  "r", "ru", null, new PB.GoalItem(player[0]), null);
    }
    //Damit  keine koordinaten negativ sind
    vertecies.forEach(function (e) {
        e.y = e.y+1;
        if (player.length>2) {
            e.x = e.x+1;
        }
    });


    return new PB.Board(vertecies, edges,  cells, start, player, realw, realh, PB.RectBoard.type);
}
PB.RectBoard.type = "Rect";

})();
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code?  The property is being changed somewhere else.

Comment: I added some more code

Comment: You can specify multiple arguments to `console.log` by separating them with commas.

Comment: *Doing so seem to change a specific property of the objects and I don't know why.* I find that hard to believe.

Comment: You *are* changing the properties in the lines `lo_ro.owner = PB.Board.boardOwner;` and `ro_ru.owner = PB.Board.boardOwner;`. Admittedly you are doing it after you've logged the objects, but the console is confusing you here. Check the duplicate.

Comment: I comment this part of the code out and have still the same result